# Ggplot2 change colour of bars. Error n too large, allowed maximum for palette

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I have the following graph based on this [dataset](https://norwayanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/pl_norwayanalytics_no/Eff6IaDkT1pGtT7GvORvpcoBjYmtrLBp63V-mq956WgRhA?e=bGu8hk)

[image]

My goal is to match the colors on each bar to the "TAG" color name.

I have tried to use a palette

```
palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(unique(tidied_pca$Tag)),name = 'Set1')
```

but i get this error

```
    Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(unique(tidied_pca$Tag)), name = "Set1") :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set1 is 9
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

The original code to render the graph is here:

```
 tidied_pca %>%
  filter(PC == "PC2") %>%
  top_n(40, abs(Contribution)) %>%
  mutate(Tag = reorder(Tag, Contribution)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Tag, Contribution, fill = Tag)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
  labs(x = "Bottle Color percentages",
       y = "Relative importance in principle component",
       title = "What color accounts for most variation PCA2")
```

Comment: Try putting all your desired colors (I guess that would be the ones on the x-axis) into one vector (like ```vec <- c("blue","red","green")```, then passing that vector for the ```fill``` argument in ```ggplot```

Comment: It doesn't work, have tried that  before. If works with you could you please post the graph image with the right colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just use the colors in the tag column, add

```
 + scale_fill_identity()
```

But for the actual error message, there's no color brewer palette that has that many distinct colors. For `Set1`, the max colors you get is 9. You *could* interpolate between those values to get more colors, but then you will probably loose the nice property of having easily distinguishable colors. You can do that with the base R `colorRampPalette` function.

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,name = 'Set1'))(length(unique(tidied_pca$Tag)))
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, could you please post the graph image with the right colors?

Comment: I need more Coffee!! It did work in fact, thank a lots!!